# Example of defining a functor in haskell between two categories (which are closely related to additive and multiplicative monoids)

Tags: haskell, categories, functor

I am trying to reconcile the math notion of functor and the haskell notion of it.
This article http://brianshourd.com/posts/2012-10-26-tilt-functors-in-haskell.html explains a bit, but maybe someone can provide an example for the following case:

Suppose i define the following categories

Add: where objects are 0,1,2,3,...., morphisms are (0+), (1+), (2+), ... (0+) is the id morph.

Mul: where objects are 0,1,2,3,...., morphisms are (0*), (1*), (2*), ... (1*) is the id morph.

The composition is (.)

How would one define a functor between these two categories in Haskell (if that is possible and if what i described above are categories at all)

Thank you

EDIT: As per @chi suggestion, i am clarifying  the question a bit. I am more interested in how you would put/translate into Haskell any functor between these two categories (as opposed to the existence of one, for example map any number to 42 and any morphism to (1*) as @chi sugested)

EDIT 2: Another way to ask this is, how do you reconcile these two statements "the Functor typeclass, which is basically for things that can be mapped over" with "Given categories C and D, a functor F:C→D is a rule that assigns to each object A in C an object F(A) in D. It also assigns to every morphism f:A→B of objects of C a morphism F(f):F(A)→F(B)". If the type constructor [] (lists) is a functor, what are the two categories it connects and how exactly is it mapping objects and morphisms between those two categories

Comment: What you've defined are not categories. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_(mathematics)#Definition) provides a definition for category so you can just check if what you've defined satisfies the definition.  It doesn't, for instance you need to have an identity morphism for each object; it doesn't make sense to talk about *the* identity morphism.

Comment: There is a single category in Haskell, called **Hask**. (Well there are others but all Haskell functors work in Hask so those other categories are of no importance here). Objects of Hask are Haskell *types*, not values. Morphisms of Hask are functions.

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta you can make `(1*)` an identity morphism for each object, no problem here.

Comment: maybe you are thinking of the monoids `(N,+,0)` and `(N,*,1)` here, as those give examples of categories as well (http://curiousskeptic.com/from-monoids-to-categories/)? You'll find those as [`Sum` and `Product`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#v:Sum)

Comment: This has nothing to do with Haskell or programming in general. You should ask this to be migrated to e.g. the Maths SE, since the question is mostly about _how_ to define the morphism, and only marginally about how to implement it in Haskell.

Comment: Still, if you really want any arbitrary functor, try mapping each object to `42` and each morphism to the identity over `42` (i.e. (*1)). This works, but it's not what you wanted, I guess, so you should refine your aims.

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta , n.p is right, (0+) 2 is 2, (0+) 3 is 3, another way to look at is: think of (0+) as an arrow, 2 (0+) 2   <-- id morphism

Comment: @chi Yes it does :) I am asking for a definition of fmap for these two categories

Comment: @chi In my mind i get what you are saying (although i am hoping for something a bit more complex), but event so, how do you map 1 to 42, 2 to 42 and (3+) to (1*) specifically, how do you define/write that in Haskell provided that you only have to define fmap (Thank you)

Comment: @Tristan you first have to say how you want to express those categories in Haskell ...

Comment: @Carsten I am not sure exactly what d you mean but probably that would be
class Category Add where
id = (0+)
(.) = (.)

there is probably a lot of things incorrect in what i just said in this comment (i am just learing H) but you get the idea of what i mean by Add and Mul categories

Comment: @Carsten, probably you mean data Mul = Mul Int

Comment: @Tristan, n.m., there are a lot of true statements in the world, the ones you guys are stating are not stated in the original question.  It says (0+) *is* the identity morphism, which doesn't make sense for a category.  You could say (0+)|{n} are the identity morphisms for each n, but that would be a charitable interpretation.  Then what about (1+)?  Is there one for every possible source object?  It's not specified.  You could have (1+)|{n} for none of the n, or all of the n, or just the odd n.   These options all generate different categories.

Comment: I'd rather the OP read the definition of Category, understand why the structures defined here are deficient, and then update the question with an unambiguous definition of the structure such that it's a category, rather than making up a charitable interpretation and then talking about something the OP doesn't intend or doesn't understand.

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta I admit it's not a very mathematical definition of a category (and the title should contain the word haskell) but then again, a category is such a broad definition that almost anything can be defined as one and from your comments i know you understood how i view it as a category.  (1,2,3 are the dots, between them there are arrows 1 (1+) 2, 2 (1+) 3, ... and (1+).(2+) = (3+) <- composition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that Haskell's `Functor` only represents a certain kind of functor: functors from the category of Haskell types and functions (`Hask`) to itself. `Functor` maps types to types (the objects of `Hask`) and functions to functions (the morphisms of `Hask`). For instance, the `Maybe` `Functor` maps any given type `a` to the type `Maybe a` and it uses `fmap` to map a given function `a -> b` to a function `Maybe a -> Maybe b`.

In the category of `Hask`, the objects are types and the morphisms are functions. Your category has integers as its objects and as a result doesn't fit the pattern of `Functor`, so the question doesn't quite make sense to ask in this form, at least not with regard to the `Functor` type class.

Comment: So the short answer is "You can't" :). Thank you. Although technically this is not the answer to the question above, it's the right answer since it explains what is a functors in Haskell (and why my particular example can't be modeled using the Functor typeclass)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the definition of the `class Category` in Haskell, you would see this.

```
class Category cat where
  id :: cat a a 
  (.) :: cat b c -> cat a b -> cat a c
```

See, if the objects in the category are `Int`s, then you would need to define those functions where `a`, `b` and `c` are `Int`s. This is fine when objects in the collection are types but not values. So you can't make them an instance of `Category`.

Also looking at `fmap`:

```
 fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

You can see it only makes sense with types (thus in the category Hask). If the objects are integers, you would pass morphisms like `4 --> 5` and `->` only works with types.

Then `(0+)` is a morphism from `Int` to `Int`. You would need a morphism from, say, 2 to 5.

Maybe it would be something like this:

```
data IntMorphism = IdMorphism | IntMorphism Int Int

comp :: IntMorphism -> IntMorphism -> IntMorphism
comp IdMorphism m = m
comp m IdMorphism = m
comp  (IntMorphism y' z) (IntMorphism x y)
  | y /= y' = error "can't compose"
  | otherwise = IntMorphism x z

f1 :: Int -> Int
f1 = (+5)

f2 :: IntMorphism -> IntMorphism
f2 IdMorphism = IdMorphism
f2 (IntMorphism x y) = IntMorphism (f1 x) (f1 y)
```

And the functor laws hold. In particular:

```
f2 (comp (IntMorphism y z) (IntMorphism x y))
= f2 (IntMorphism x z)
= IntMorphism (f1 x) (f1 z)
= comp (IntMorphism (f1 y) (f1 z)) (IntMorphism (f1 x) (f1 y))
= comp (f2 (IntMorphism y z)) (f2 (IntMorphism x y))
```

Of course, as it deals with values, it can't use the typeclasses defined in base and it is all done at runtime.

Comment: Than you for trying to come up with an answer to a poorly formulated question :) As i said in my edits, probably i should have asked how to view haskell functors as mathematical functors. Thank you anyway

Comment: Oh okay, in that case they are endofunctors in the category Hask, the category of Haskell types but I guess you got that from the other comments on your post.